# 4.0.4 Facebook SSO - Android Key Hash changed?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, facebook-android-sdk

App with Facebook SDK SSO was working fine in 2.2, now upgraded Samsung Galaxy (both a II and III for testing) to 4.0.4 and now getting this from FB SSO SDK:

```
E/fbLogin(8286): invalid_key:Android key mismatch. Your key "<<omitted>>" does not match the allowed keys specified in your application settings. Check your application settings at http://www.facebook.com/developers
```

So I went and updated the key hash on fb/developers, and yep, it's working fine again.

It's odd- it worked with the original value in a 2.2 AVD, and the 4.0.3 AVD, but on both 4.0.4 physical devices, I'm getting the above error.

Is there something different going on with 4.0.4 that's causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no answer seems coming.  For those who come across this, just copy the key hash in the error message to the fb developers site, and you should be good to go.